# JSON-RPC for react project

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, rpc, json-rpc

In a React app, I need to work with JSON-RPC API. I found some libraries that act as a JSON-RPC client. But it's not entirely clear to me whether I should install with a special client. I tried sending a request using axios and it looks like everything is working. Or am I missing something?

Therefore, I will be grateful if you answer at least one of my questions:

- Сan use the `fetch` or `axios` to send and receive data in json-rtc
  format?

  ```
  axios.post(`/link-to-rpc-api`, {
    "jsonrpc": '2.0',
    "method": 'transformMessage',
    "id": 1,
    "params": {
      "message": 'Test',
    }
  });
  ```
- If so, how can I execute batch requests?
- Are there any best practices/libraries for json-rpc to work in a
  React app?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Axios of fetch which you can, you should read the [specification of the JSON-RPC 2.- protocol](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification). Libraries did that and you have clients. The specification has everything you need to know (also how to send batches). It's not difficult to read and it's short.